# Python: how to get the associated value in a string?

Tags: python

sys.stdout.write("metadata-structure: %s\n"%(metadatastructure))

gives

```
metadata-structure: # generated using pymatgen
data_C
_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M   'P 1'
_cell_length_a   2.51636378
_cell_length_b   2.51636378
_cell_length_c   2.51636378
_cell_angle_alpha   60.00000000
_cell_angle_beta   60.00000000
_cell_angle_gamma   60.00000000
_symmetry_Int_Tables_number   1
_chemical_formula_structural   C
_chemical_formula_sum   C2
_cell_volume   11.2669217281
_cell_formula_units_Z   2
loop_
 _symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id
 _symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
  1  'x, y, z'
loop_
 _atom_site_type_symbol
 _atom_site_label
 _atom_site_symmetry_multiplicity
 _atom_site_fract_x
 _atom_site_fract_y
 _atom_site_fract_z
 _atom_site_occupancy
  C  C1  1  0.250000  0.250000  0.250000  1
  C  C2  1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1
```

Now, I want to extract 2.156 associated with the variable
_cell_length_a

How to process this long string?
I am not good at regular expressions.

Comment: `_cell_length_a   2.51636378` has `2.51636378` not `2.156`?

Comment: Is this a string or a file?

Comment: Welcome @EdGan. First off, the reason you're being downvoted is because the quality of your question is not the best. A good question includes things like what you've tried, how it fails, expected results and obviously properly formatted. So please keep that in mind next time. I don't want you to be discouraged to learn so I won't flame on you like most folks here. Here is a solution for the regex you're looking for: https://regex101.com/r/sNltS2/2 As to know how to use it code, the info already exists, start with the official python regex docs or any tutorial you find.

Comment: yes. I tried to key in the number first and then changed it  later.

Comment: In the solution above there two groups, first one contains the string and the second one contains the value you're looking for. Just parse the extracted string into a float and you're good.

Comment: What is the type of `metadatastructure`?

Comment: this is a long string, how can I even start to process.

Comment: guys be gentle with me, i am not pro in posting in this stack overflow thing. I tried to format output using {}  but it says put your code here...

Comment: @EdGan you can extract everything in between ` _cell_length_a` and `_cell_length_b` and then `strip` the whitespaces.

Comment: metadatastructure = data["metadata"]["structure"]
sys.stdout.write("metadata-structure: %s\n"%(metadatastructure))

Comment: what is the shortcut to get a display a code nicely.. kind of stupid questions.. sorry

Comment: i try to communicate properly

Comment: It is not a file, but a long string. It has many "lines" separated by \n. One line starts with _cell_length_a  and besides it is a value I tried to get.

Comment: @EdGan see if the asnwer posted below helps?

Comment: On a related note: somewhere someone said my post was not properly formatted. But i am rather new with this platform (and expect many more to be intimidated by it). It seems there is no preview of my  post before submit (or there is really such mechanism in place where i just missed since i am dumb?). In many linux forums i was able to edit until i am satisfied before I hit submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to look for `_cell_length_a` (or any other key), followed by some spaces, and then capture whatever comes after that until the end of that line.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"_cell_length_a\s+([0-9.]+)", metadatastructure)
['2.51636378', '2.51636378']
```

Or using a list-comprehension with `splitlines`, `startswith` and `split`:

```
>>> [line.split()[-1] for line in metadatastructure.splitlines() if line.startswith("_cell_length_a")]
['2.51636378', '2.51636378']
```

Note that both ways, the result is still a string (or list of strings) and has to be converted to `float`:

```
>>> [float(x) for x in _]
[2.51636378, 2.51636378]
```

---

About your follow-up question from comments: "Here _cell_formula_units_Z is 2. Now, I need to extract the next 2 lines after the line with _atom_site_occupancy", try this:

```
lines_iter = iter(metadatastructure.splitlines())
for line in lines_iter:
    if line.startswith("_cell_formula_units_Z"):
        z = int(line.split()[-1])
    if "_atom_site_occupancy" in line:
        for _ in range(z):
            print(next(lines_iter))
```

Comment: alength = re.findall(r"_cell_length_a\s+([0-9.]+)",metadatastructure)

Comment: NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: alength = re.findall(r"_cell_length_a\s+([0-9.]+)",metadatastructure)
sys.stdout.write("alength = %s\n"%(alength))

Comment: output is this: alength = [u'2.51636378']

Comment: @EdGan You have to `import re`. The output looks okay, but might have to be converted to `float` for further processing. BTW, why are you `sys.stdout.write` instead of just `print`?

Comment: i was told print is to be phased out by python3. Hence i avoid print consciously. `listnum= re.findall(r"_cell_length_a\s+([0-9.]+)",metadatastructure)  alength = float(listnum[0])` solves it. Thanks @tobias_k.

Comment: @EdGan The `print` _statement_ has merely been replaced with the `print(...)` _function_.

Comment: Here _cell_formula_units_Z is 2. Now, I need to extract the next 2 lines after the line with _atom_site_occupancy so I can process each of  line later for the coordinates. Any quick shortcut?

Comment: I have learned C, Fortran, ... but I am surprised by python! Thanks!

Comment: For the cryptic (to me!) last two lines, I use `for x in range(z): print(lines_iter.next())`   Comment?

Comment: @EdGan Yes, that's just as good, if not better. Maybe use `next(lines_iter)` though, as `iter.next` was removed in Python 3. Edited.

Comment: I was thinking a bit hard on `lines_iter = iter(metastructure.splitlines())`, which will create a list of lines in the intermediate step (which incur cost if it has a few thousand lines). Say I use `f = metastructure.splitlines()` , so i could probably loop over the list f, while making it less cryptic? I searched on web, it says the main purpose of iterator is for efficiency since it saves resource space. However it seems whether we use iter()  or f = metastructure.splitlines() make no diff as far as speed is concerned.

Comment: Indeed I changed the line to `lines_iter = metastructure.splitlines()` the program runs okay. No need iter(). Comment?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Iter(metadatastructure.splitlines) is needed since I run into ` AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'`. Okay with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is: `.*(_cell_length_a)\s*([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)`. It will return two groups as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/sNltS2/2

Parse the second group into float and monkey is your uncle.

Although I suspect you might not need it as it looks like this data is structured, so if you can parse it into a class you'll be able to access all the values etc.